# How can i change text to white?

Tags: css

Here is my HTML code, i want to change text "GIMME YOUR NAME" to white.

What CSS selector i need to use to change this text color.

```
<input type="text" name="_imie" class="error_message required  the_input_element  aling_left align_center style_bold form-control" data-onfocus-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" data-drop-focus-swadow="1" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Wymagane" title="" data-secondary-message="" data-original-brd-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" placeholder="GIMME YOUR NAME" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 30px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;;" data-math-equation="" data-original-math-equation="" autocomplete="disabled">
```

Here is what i tried

```
::placeholder {
color: white}

.input[type=text]{
color:white}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `.input` but `input`, because the dot selector: `.` selects classes not elements.

So your code would look like:

```
input[type=text]{
color:white}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but this not resolved my problem :(

Comment: You set the color of the font in the `style= color: rgb(255, 255, 255)`. Take that out of your html. I would take all of the `style=""` part out completely if you are going to add your own custom css in a seperate section.

Comment: Okay sorry, I misread your question. Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/ Try changing `::placeholder` to `input[type=text]::placeholder` If you are on a different web browser than chrome or safari then you need to add `input[type=text]::-moz-placholder` for firefox

Comment: Yesss!! input[type=text]::placeholder was the key! Thanks for help!